# Передача между компонентами во vue 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть приложение с разбитыми на компоненты в разных файлах , используеться `vue router` , 1 компонент при нажатии на кнопку строит таблицу в зависимости от данных в `data` другого компонента , как взять эти данных ?

Answer (score 0):

Передать необходимые данные в компонент, который строит таблицу через props.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать vuex для глобального стейта.
Если не использовать vuex, то уже в зависимости от иерархии в которой эти компоненты находятся. По идеологии vue вверх "события", вниз "пропсы". Соответственно, если это абсолютно не связанные компоненты (братья/сестры). То им понадобится общий родительский. Тогда - по нажатию кнопки допустим, в первом компоненте вы в методе вызываете $emit('createTable'), в общем родительском компоненте, отлавливаете это событие и в шаблоне прописываете к второму компоненту 
     `<second @createTable="$emit('dataSended', data)"></second>`
, в родительском компоненте уже отлавливаете это событие и к первому компоненту через props опускаете необходимые данные. Как только данные приходят отрисовываете таблицу.